# Import Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, import, android-manifest

I have imported a project in my Eclipse. I have imported other android projects in same way. And they are working fine. But in this case it is giving the following error message and R.java file is not creating.

> AndroidManifest.xml:2: error: No
>   resource identifier found for
>   attribute 'installLocation' in package
>   'android'

What is the solution of this problem?

Comment: show your manifest file, please.

Comment: Check your Android library, that is properly loaded or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your target sdk version should be a minimum of 2.2 (Froyo) in your manifest file

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```